# How do I jump out of a foreach loop in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, foreach

How do I break out of a `foreach` loop in C# if one of the elements meets the requirement?

For example:

```
foreach(string s in sList){
      if(s.equals("ok")){
       //jump foreach loop and return true
     }
    //no item equals to "ok" then return false
}
```

Comment: Funny. In Python you'd simply do `return "ok" in sList:` - isn't there something comparable in C#?

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker: Of course there is, see spender's answer.  In fact, after getting used to Linq, a lot of imperative code looks like cave drawings.

Answer (score 315, accepted):

```
foreach (string s in sList)
{
    if (s.equals("ok"))
        return true;
}

return false;
```

Alternatively, if you need to do some other things after you've found the item:

```
bool found = false;
foreach (string s in sList)
{
    if (s.equals("ok"))
    {
        found = true;
        break; // get out of the loop
    }
}

// do stuff

return found;
```

Comment: I would suggest the second example would be better rewritten to `bool found = callFunctionInFirstCodeSnipper(list); // do stuff`

Comment: It's not related to the question strictly. But, I found this question in my searches and found that I was ultimately looking for the keyword `continue`. Which is similar to these answers but it skips to the next item in the loop.

Answer (score 117):

Use `break;` and this will exit the foreach loop

Answer (score 61):

You could avoid explicit loops by taking the LINQ route:

```
sList.Any(s => s.Equals("ok"))
```

Comment: or just use `Contains("ok")`.

Comment: @Graham Clark: `Contains` assumes you're iterating over an `ICollection<T>`.  `Any` would work on anything that of type `IEnumerable<T>`, and in this case question doesn't explicitly indicate what kind of collection it's iterating over (a `List` is a pretty fair guess though).

Answer (score 37):

```
foreach (var item in listOfItems) {
  if (condition_is_met)
    // Any processing you may need to complete here...
    break; // return true; also works if you're looking to
           // completely exit this function.
}
```

Should do the trick. The break statement will just end the execution of the loop, while the return statement will obviously terminate the entire function. Judging from your question you may want to use the return true; statement.

Answer (score 10):

Use the 'break' statement to break out of a foreach loop.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `break` which jumps out of the closest enclosing loop, or you can just directly `return true`

Answer (score 3):

how about:

```
return(sList.Contains("ok"));
```

That should do the trick if all you want to do 
is check for an "ok" and return the answer ...

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(string s in sList)
{
    if(s.equals("ok"))
    {
             return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

Answer (score 1):

Either return straight out of the loop:

```
foreach(string s in sList){
   if(s.equals("ok")){
      return true;
   }
}

// if you haven't returned by now, no items are "ok"
return false;
```

Or use `break`:

```
bool isOk = false;
foreach(string s in sList){
   if(s.equals("ok")){
      isOk = true;
      break; // jump out of the loop
   }
}

if(isOk)
{
    // do something
}
```

However, in your case it might be better to do something like this:

```
if(sList.Contains("ok"))
{
    // at least one element is "ok"
}
else
{
   // no elements are "ok"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a direct answer to your question but there is a much easier way to do what you want. If you are using .NET 3.5 or later, at least. It is called [Enumerable.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880.aspx)

```
bool found = sList.Contains("ok");
```

Answer (score -2):

this is an old question but just thought I would add this answer

you could also use a `While` loop like this

```
string sample = "";
while(sample == "")
{
    foreach(DataRow row in DataTable.Rows
        sample = row["somecolumn"].ToString();
}
```

once the string 'sample' no longer = "" the loop will end

Comment: Perhaps code that would compile would help illustrate what you're suggesting?

Comment: Well? I just tried to put this into action and there was more overhead than I had expected.  The use of the 'break;' statement would be a better way to go.

Comment: You do understand that this code still doesn't compile?

Comment: Why are you introducing `DataRow row in DataTable.Rows` when the original question didn't have that at all?

Comment: The original question was how to exit a `foreach` loop, and I was just trying to offer a method of exiting a loop using `while`.  I would just ignore my answer and use the answer from Francis Gilbert or mbillard or the one from Cody.  Thanks for the criticism Enigmativity.

Comment: If you're going to come in late to a question then your answer should be novel or razor focused. You haven't done either of those. BTW, I didn't criticise you or your answer at all. I have only asked questions. When we do criticise on this site we do so constructively so that we can improve the quality of the questions and answers. That's all I'm trying to do here.

Answer (score -3):

```
var ind=0;
foreach(string s in sList){
    if(s.equals("ok")){
        return true;
    }
    ind++;
}
if (ind==sList.length){
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure `$` isn't valid C# syntax.

Comment: probably not, im a javascript/php guy. but there is enough code here to apply a working solution... i removed the $ and added var.. probably still not c+

Comment: actually `var` is a perfectly valid C# keyword, so you're good